# How to ignore '#' character from angular route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular application, by using $stateProvider i have configured few angular states. but when i target to any state, the url appear '#' character  like: http://localhost:63808/#/login, instead of this url i want to configure like: http://localhost:63808/login. here is my app.js code.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]);

mainApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/payment');
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'Dashboard/templates/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .state('payment', {
        url: '/payment',
        templateUrl: 'Dashboard/templates/payment/payment.html',
        controller: 'TransactionsController'
    })
    .state('institute', {
        url: '/institute',
        templateUrl: 'Dashboard/templates/institute.html',
        controller: 'InstituteController'
    })
    .state('pinverification', {
        url: '/pinverification',
        templateUrl: 'Dashboard/templates/PIN/verification.html',
        controller: 'PINVerificationController'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Config your app with $locationProvider:

```js
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    
    // Routes
 });
```

And HTML :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

hashPrefix removes the '!'

Source : https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: Glad it helps you :)

Comment: inside page click working nice, but once i hit the url reload button it's not working, not found error.

Comment: Are you talking about the browser reload button ?

Comment: if i paste this link http://localhost:63808/login to browser url, and enter hit button, then not working. but if i http://localhost:63808 its working and coming like http://localhost:63808/login. but i want to direct hit url like others website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147051/discussion-between-sebu-and-zooly).

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML5 Mode

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

---

> once i hit the url reload button it's not working, not found error.

HTML5 mode requires URL rewriting.

From the Docs:

> ## HTML5 Mode
>
> ## Server side
>
> **Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side**, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a `<base>` tag is also important for this case, as it allows AngularJS to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handled by the application.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Using $location (HTML5 Mode Server Side)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side)

### For angular applications running under NodeJS and ExpressJS

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

// serve angular front end files from root path
router.use('/', express.static('app', { redirect: false }));

// rewrite virtual urls to angular app to enable refreshing of internal pages
router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('app/index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

### For angular applications running under IIS on Windows

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS - Enable HTML5 Mode Page Refresh Without 404 Errors in NodeJS and IIS](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/angularjs-enable-html5-mode-page-refresh-without-404-errors-in-nodejs-and-iis).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')`

Try reading [this article.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) Very good explanation.

You can try something like following:

```
angular.module( 'app', [ ] ).config(function( $locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```